# Why bindvalue not insertting into table?

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

I have these query:

```
$sql="insert into m_ruangan (RG_ID,RG_Nama,RG_Kapasitas,RG_Keterangan,RG_AktifYN,RG_UpdateID,RG_UpdateTime) ".
        "values (:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4,:field5,:field6,:field7); ";

$stmt->bindValue(':field1', $result['RG_ID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':field2', $result['RG_Nama'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':field3', $result['RG_Kapasitas'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':field4', $result['RG_Keterangan'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':field5', $result['RG_AktifYN'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':field6', $result['RG_UpdateID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':field7', $result['RG_UpdateTime'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt =$m_f->cdb->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

When I run it it show no error but the value will not inserted in the table. 
I'm using the looping for inserting

Any idea why it goes wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `prepare` your sql statement prior to `bindValue`,

```
$stmt =$m_f->cdb->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':field1', $result['RG_ID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':field2', $result['RG_Nama'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
.........          
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you don't see an error. Are you sure you enabled PDO errors?

```
$connection = new PDO($connection_string); 
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

You can choose one of these:

```
PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT: Just set error codes.
PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING: Raise E_WARNING. 
PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION: Throw exceptions.
```

EDIT: I think the comment of Rikesh describes the problem.